# how to make interstatial ads come in every 5 minutes using angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

hello there im new for anngualrJs and ionic framework. i want to  make interstatial ads come in every 5 minutes using angualrJs  in ionic 1 project. Any body help me.

My code is

```
admobid = {};

if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-2343423432432423/324324324324',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-2343423432432423/324324324324'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-2343423432432423/324324324324',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-2343423432432423/324324324324'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-2343423432432423/324324324324',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-2343423432432423/324324324324'
    };
}

if(window.AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
adId:admobid.banner,
isTesting:false,
position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
autoShow:true} );

if(Window.AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId:admobid.interstitial,
    isTesting:false,
    autoShow:false
  });

});
```

i dont know where to add the code for interstatial ads to come in every 5 min

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the complete example here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showInterstitialAd

Be carefull with this, Google will be willing to reject your app if it is considered that interstitials are shown unexpectedly while user is reading app content.

Basically the idea is to set a timeout and request a new ad. When the ad is available, you show it and reset the timeo